# ModSecurity dependency not found?

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, web-server, redhat, mod-security

```
1. yum groupinstall 'Development tools'
2. yum install -y geoip-devel libcurl-devel libxml2-devel libxslt-devel libgb-devel lmdb-devel openssl-devel pcre-devel perl-ExtUtils-Embed yajl-devel zlib-devel
3. cd /opt
4. git clone --depth 1 -b v3/master https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity.git
5. cd ModSecurity
6. git submodule init
7. git submodule update
8. ./build.sh
9. ./configure
```

And below is the result

[image]

As we can tell, step 2 we have installed yajl-devel and geoip-devel but why is the dependencies not found?

**UPDATES**:

Realized when I try to install `geoip-devel` and `yajl-devel` individually, both giving me No Package available error. Wondering how should I install them?

Below is the output

```
[root@ip nginx]# yum install -y geoip-devel
Loaded plugins: amazon-id, rhui-lb, search-disabled-repos
No package geoip-devel available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The packages you are missing are in the RHEL optional channel, which you need to enable.

```
yum-config-manager --enable rhui-REGION-rhel-server-extras rhui-REGION-rhel-server-optional
```